# Generate pipe delimited file through php

Tags: php, csv, fputcsv

My code generates a txt file using PHP's fputcsv function.

For the delimiter, I am trying to use '|'

```
$query = mysql_query("SELECT email, emailSource FROM session WHERE is_complete='1' ORDER by sessionid ASC")

$filename= 'here.txt';

$fp = fopen( $filename,'w');


fputcsv($fp, array('Email address', 'Email Source'));

if(mysql_numrows($query) > 0) {

    while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($query, MYSQL_ASSOC)) {
            fputcsv($fp, array_values($row));
    }
}


fclose($fp);
$contents = file_get_contents($filename);
$contents = str_replace(",", "|", $contents);
file_put_contents($filename, $contents);
```

The result I get is all on one line instead of showing the values on a seperate line and I also have "" around the headers.

```
"Email address"|"Email Source"|blah@blah.com|hi|
```

instead of this:

```
Email address|Email Source|

blah@blah.com|hi|
```

Please can someone tell me what I am doing wrong. Is it because I am using fputcsv and saving to a txt file?

Comment: rather than using str_replace() why not use fputcsv() specifying the | as your delimiter argument?

Comment: fputcsv adds a line break at the end of each line, are you sure its not there?

Comment: Also, you close $fp file handler before putting the content (see above comment as well)

Comment: @Ayesh K, that's correct. File_put_contents opens a completely new handle.

Comment: Well I tried having | as my delimiter but it didn't work. The thing is that it works when i save the file as a csv but i need to save the file as a text. When I save it as a text, the result shows up on one line and with commas still.

Comment: how do you view it afterwards? browsers font know what a line break is, make sure you use a text editor.

Comment: Dagon thank you so much, i just used notepad++ and it showed up. Now I just need to get it to not show the ""

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Get rid of the str_replace / file_get_contents/ file_put_contents block. Instead of `fputcsv($fp, array('...'))`, use `fputcsv($fp, array('...'), '|');`

Comment: Thanks David, but my main error now is that I still see the "" in the header

Comment: So set the fourth param of fputcsv to ''. I.e.: fputcsv($fp, array('...'), '|', '');

Comment: that's the enclosure param, which is what you're referring to